# CSS: Parent-Div does not grow with it's children (horizontal)

Tags: css, width, parent

I would like the parent-div (red) to grow with the green child-div.
Now it just stops at the viewport.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
<head>
<title>simple document</title>
<style type="text/css">
 * {
  font-family: verdana;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin: 30px; background: red; padding: 10px;">
 <div style="background: green; width: 2000px;">dxyf</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want to use display:table; since it does not work well in IE.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not make the parent div 2000 pixels? That should work.

Comment: @Joop Obviously he wants the parent width to depend on the child width (which could vary depending on the content)

Answer (score 32):

Use `display: inline-block;` on the parent `<div>` and it will work as expected

Comment: Yeah! That's great! Thank you, I never thought this would work in IE too - just learnt something useful!

Comment: Quirksmode (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) says that you can't use the `inline-block` display on elements that don't default to `display: inline` for IE 6 and 7. Have you tested it in those?

Comment: @Alex True, but this is the forward-thinking solution that adheres to the standard. To address older browsers, conditional comments can be used to apply a `float` to the parent element (if needed).

Comment: I solved it by changing the div to a span und give the parent display:inline-block;
This way IE 6 - 8 and FF will display the site correct.
I just have to test if this will work in FF2 too..
But anyway - thanks!

Comment: Err.. apparently we need the div (no inline-element). Is there a way without conditional comments? Pure CSS? Would be awesome :)

Comment: Omg finally found the solution that works after hours of research, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make the parent div float:left; and it will be expanded as desired.

Comment: In FF2 this would not work _properly_ - the child grows larger than the parent.. how could we solve this? Apparently this is due the margin of the parent-div.

Comment: You will either need a clear element or you can use the quirksmode solution posted below.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but here's what I do to fix the problem:

Add the clear INSIDE the parent at the bottom, and make the parent overflow: hidden.

Here's the modified code:

```
.clear{
    clear: both;
    /* make sure there is no height set to it */
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0em;
}

<div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 30px; background: red; padding: 10px;">
 <div style="background: green; width: 2000px;">dxyf</div>
 <div class="clear">/div>
</div>
```

Works in FF3 and IE7, but not tested in other browsers though.

Hope to, at least, help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use display:table; on the parent div. Or you can put the parent div into a cell of a table.

Answer (score 0):

There's too much complicated advice here. Here's a tip: instead of tinkering with table-cells, and clear and floats, just make sure the child has a border that's equivalent to the padding you were looking for the parent. Borders are always drawn outside, so it'll do what you want.

This should work...

```
<div style="margin: 30px; background: red;">
 <div style="background: green; width: 2000px; border: 10px red solid">dxyf</div>
</div>
```

...in all browsers, without a problem. HTH.

Answer (score -1):

See [this solution](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) from quirksmode.org.  It's pretty simple, just apply this class to the container/parent div:

```
div.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```