# How to expand parent div when child div appears on show with fixed width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I expand the parent div(auto) when the child div(fixed width) is shown onclick?

**Objective:** 
When I click the link, the child div will appear and the parent div should expand(scale) to the width of the child div. The child div should not overflow outside of the parent div.

Thanks :)

http://jsfiddle.net/aebLS/3/

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $('#mybox').show();
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a id="mylink" href="javascript:void(0);">SHOW BOX</a><hr />
<div class="parent">
    <div class="header">Header Content</div>
    <div id="mybox" class="child">Content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body { 
    font-family:verdana; 
    font-size:10px;
}
.parent {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.child {
    display:none;
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background:lightblue;
}
.header {
    width:auto;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: You want to expand it to how big? in your example it is already wider than the child, do you want to add on the width of the child to the already wide parent?

Comment: [you could do something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/aebLS/5/)

Comment: @DGS: I want to expand it to the width of the child div so it will scale its width and not overflow outside of the parent div.

Comment: Might be best to add an image showing the actual problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

```
body { 
    font-family:verdana; 
    font-size:10px;
}
.parent {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.child {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background:lightblue;
}
.header {
    width:auto;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aebLS/10/)

Just need to add `display: inline-block` to the parent

```
.parent {
    border:1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

From [CSS: Parent-Div does not grow with it's children (horizontal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545331/css-parent-div-does-not-grow-with-its-children-horizontal)

Answer (score -1):

Change your div place and show result.

Like this,

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="header">Header Content
        <div id="mybox" class="child">Content</div></div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aebLS/6/)

Comment: Does not achieve what the question asks for.

Comment: He need expand parent div and chid div show in parent div and this to correct way

Comment: resize your jsfiddle output window so that the parent is less than 400px wide and you will see that it still overflows

Comment: @DGS I am doing some change in old code and update not create new css,js and html that for you see parent size large. Now chaeck this link and show the new output.. http://jsfiddle.net/aebLS/8/

Comment: The problem the question is trying to solve is having a parent with an auto width and a child with a fixed width. You have added a fixed width to the parent which is not what the question is asking for.